# Generic Dictionary in Session .Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a generic class called SessionManager to control the types of variables I store in session. I have been doing it for String, Integer, List(Of T) without any issues like this.

```
Public NotInheritable Class SessionManager

    '''<remarks>
    '''Private constructor to prevent instantiation of, or inheritance from, this class.
    '''</remarks>
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub


       Private Const _PropertyOfSomeClass As String = "PROPERY_OF_SOME_CLASS"
       Private Const _ListOfSomeClass As String = "LIST_OF_SOME_CLASS"

       Public Shared Property PropertyOfSomeClass() As SomeClass
            Get
                Return GetFromSession(Of SomeClass)(_PropertyOfSomeClass)
            End Get
            Set(value As SomeClass)
                SetInSession(Of SomeClass)(_PropertyOfSomeClass, value)
            End Set
        End Property


        Public Shared Property ListOfSomeClass() As List(Of SomeClass)
            Get
                Return GetFromSessionAsList(Of SomeClass)(_ListOfSomeClass)
            End Get
            Set(value As List(Of SomeClass))
                SetInSessionAsList(Of SomeClass)(_ListOfSomeClass, value)
            End Set
        End Property


        Private Shared Function GetFromSession(Of T)(key As String) As T
            Dim obj As Object = HttpContext.Current.Session(key)
            If obj Is Nothing Then
                Return Nothing
            End If
            Return DirectCast(obj, T)
        End Function

        Private Shared Function GetFromSessionAsList(Of T)(key As String) As List(Of T)
            Dim obj As Object = HttpContext.Current.Session(key)
            If obj Is Nothing Then
                SetInSessionAsList(Of T)(key, New List(Of T))
                Return New List(Of T)
            End If
            Return DirectCast(obj, List(Of T))
        End Function

        Private Shared Sub SetInSession(Of T)(key As String, value As T)
            If value Is Nothing Then
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(key)
            Else
                HttpContext.Current.Session(key) = value
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Shared Sub SetInSessionAsList(Of T)(key As String, value As List(Of T))
            If value Is Nothing Then
                HttpContext.Current.Session(key) = New List(Of T)
            Else
                HttpContext.Current.Session(key) = value
            End If
        End Sub

End Class
```

I would like to do the same for Dictionary(Of T, T). I would like 2 generic private methods for Dictionary(Of T, T) for getting and setting; GetFromSessionAsDictionary and SetInSessionAsDictionary. (When nothing returns empty dictionary like the List(Of T) properties and sets in session)

And this should allow me to create as many public properties of Type Dictionary (e.g. Dictionary(Of String, String), Dictionary(Of String, Integer)) as possible to store in session. Is it possible to do? If so, how? I have already had a go at it but it's confused the hell out of me.

**EDIT**

This is what I have ended up doing after trying to make it generic Dictionary(Of T, T), and it works without any issues. What I want instead is a solution that would not constraint the type to Dictionary(Of String, Integer).

Private Const _Dictionary1OfStringInt As String = "DICTIONARY_1_OF_STRING_INT"

```
Public Shared Property DictionaryOf As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Get
        Return GetFromSessionAsDictionary(_Dictionary1OfStringInt)
    End Get
    Set(value As Dictionary(Of String, Integer))
        SetInSessionAsDictionary(_Dictionary1OfStringInt, value)
    End Set
End Property

Private Shared Function GetFromSessionAsDictionary(key As String) As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Dim obj As Object = HttpContext.Current.Session(key)
    If obj Is Nothing Then
        SetInSessionAsDictionary(key, New Dictionary(Of String, Integer))
        Return New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    End If
    Return DirectCast(obj, Dictionary(Of String, Integer))
End Function

Private Shared Sub SetInSessionAsDictionary(key As String, value As Dictionary(Of String, Integer))
    If value Is Nothing Then
        HttpContext.Current.Session(key) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Else
        HttpContext.Current.Session(key) = value
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT 2**

Well, I did it myself. I was confused about passing TKey, TValue as I thought T could only be passed once.

```
Private Shared Function GetFromSessionAsDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)(key As String) As Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
    Dim obj As Object = HttpContext.Current.Session(key)
    If obj Is Nothing Then
        SetInSessionAsDictionary(key, New Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue))
        Return New Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
    End If
    Return DirectCast(obj, Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue))
End Function

Private Shared Sub SetInSessionAsDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)(key As String, value As Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue))
    HttpContext.Current.Session(key) = If(value, New Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)())
End Sub
```

Thanks for advising!

Comment: What exactly confused you? Where are you having difficulties?

Comment: @Hiral can you show what you've tried for Dictonary(Of T, T). It would help

Comment: Also just fun note you can do something like `HttpContext.Current.Session(key) = If(value, New List(Of T)` instead of checking for nothing everywhere.

Comment: I have added what I have done, do you want me to post the non-working code too? Just requires me to undo all changes I made to serve my purpose temporarily and get back to where I was when I posted the question.

Comment: Be careful with Dictionary because its not serializable, which can cause problems with out of process session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself, sorry for wasting your time, Thanks!

```
Private Shared Function GetFromSessionAsDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)(key As String) As Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
    Dim obj As Object = HttpContext.Current.Session(key)
    If obj Is Nothing Then
        SetInSessionAsDictionary(key, New Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue))
        Return New Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
    End If
    Return DirectCast(obj, Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue))
End Function

Private Shared Sub SetInSessionAsDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)(key As String, value As Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue))
    HttpContext.Current.Session(key) = If(value, New Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)())
End Sub
```